# Selenium + Jenkins - Stuck at Checking Resource aliases

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have a problem, I'm trying to run Selenium on Jenkins but I'm always stuck at step "INFO - Checking Resource aliases".

This is my command: 
`java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite *firefox http://test.test.com /home/jenkins/selenium/test/suite.html /home/jenkins/selenium/output/firefox-results.html`

Here is my Test Suite :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
    <title>Test Suite</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="suiteTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="selenium">
      <tbody>
        <tr><td><b>Test Suite</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td><a href="test">SimpleTest</a></td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here my Test Case :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="selenium.base" href="http://test.test.com/" />
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">test</td></tr>
    </thead><tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>open</td>
     <td>/login</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>type</td>
     <td>name=login</td>
     <td>test@test.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>name=password</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>type</td>
     <td>name=password</td>
     <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>clickAndWait</td>
     <td>css=button.btn.btn-primary</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>css=i.fa.fa-sign-out</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>click</td>
     <td>id=bot2-Msg1</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the full output :

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Functional Test Suite Staging (test)/workspace
 java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite *firefox     http://test.test.com /home/jenkins/selenium/test/suite.html /home/jenkins/selenium/output/firefox-results.html
[workspace] $ java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite *firefox http://staging.assessfirst.com /home/jenkins/selenium/test/suite.html /home/jenkins/selenium/output/firefox-results.html
08:50:13.115 INFO - Launching a standalone server
08:50:13.179 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 23.25-b01
08:50:13.179 INFO - OS: Linux 3.2.0-59-virtual amd64
08:50:13.221 INFO - v2.43.1, with Core v2.43.1. Built from revision 5163bce
08:50:13.405 INFO - Default driver org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match with current platform: LINUX
08:50:13.477 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
08:50:13.479 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
08:50:13.480 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
08:50:13.481 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
08:50:13.481 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
08:50:13.673 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@5ba5e310
08:50:13.673 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
08:50:13.681 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
08:50:13.681 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@38476a1d
jar:file:/var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar!/customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME
08:50:13.866 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
08:50:15.672 INFO - Launching Firefox...
08:50:18.077 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
08:50:25.858 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your arguments for `-htmlSuite` in a string.  It's possible that it is interpreting those as seperate arguments

```
java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox     http://test.test.com /home/jenkins/selenium/test/suite.html" /home/jenkins/selenium/output/firefox-results.html
```